# Actionable push notification in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

```
        var acceptAction = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier("AcceptAction", "Accept", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);
            var declineAction = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier("DeclineAction", "Decline", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

                // Create category
            var meetingInviteCategory = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier("MeetingInvitation",
                new UNNotificationAction[] { acceptAction, declineAction }, new string[] { }, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.CustomDismissAction);

            // Register category
            var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { meetingInviteCategory };
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));
```

**how can you receive a custom actionable push notification and where need to put the above code in which file?**

Comment: Notification permission should be requested as soon as the app launches by adding the above code to the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate and setting the desired notification type (UNAuthorizationOptions) . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows

Comment: I will post it as answer , could you accept it ? Would help more people .

Answer (score 0):

Before an iOS app can send notifications to the user the app must be registered with the system and, because a notification is an interruption to the user, an app must explicitly request permission before sending them.

Notification permission should be requested as soon as the app launches by adding the following code to the **FinishedLaunching** method of the **AppDelegate** and setting the desired notification type (UNAuthorizationOptions):

```
...
using UserNotifications;
...



 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   {
       ....

        //after iOS 10
        if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10,0))
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter center = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;

            center.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge, (bool arg1, NSError arg2) =>
                 {

                 });

            center.Delegate = new NotificationDelegate();
        }

        else if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {

            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert| UIUserNotificationType.Badge| UIUserNotificationType.Sound,new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);

        }

        return true;
    }
```

New to iOS 10, an app can handle Notifications differently when it is in the foreground and a Notification is triggered. By providing aUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and implementing theUserNotificationCentermethod, the app can take over responsibility for displaying the Notification. For example:

```
using System;
using ObjCRuntime;
using UserNotifications;


namespace xxx
{
 public class NotificationDelegate:UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
   {
    public NotificationDelegate()
    {
    }

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        // Do something with the notification
        Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);

        // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
        // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert|UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    }


    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        // Take action based on Action ID
        switch (response.ActionIdentifier)
        {
            case "reply":
                // Do something
                break;
            default:
                // Take action based on identifier
                if (response.IsDefaultAction)
                {
                    // Handle default action...
                }
                else if (response.IsDismissAction)
                {
                    // Handle dismiss action
                }
                break;
        }

        // Inform caller it has been handled
        completionHandler();
    }

  }
}
```